# Cycling through a C array with global counter

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have an array of strings that I would like to dynamically change when a user input a string. This 2D array has a fixed size, say `char A[N][BUFF_MAX]` will store `N` strings each of size at most `BUFF_MAX`. I want this array to cycle through, that is, the most recent input should be stored in `A[0]` and so on.

So far, I have no problem implementing the above. My problem arises when the user inputs more than `N` strings. At this point I would like to store the *last* `N` inputs and discard the rest to only use `N` cells. Shifting can be done using using `strcpy`.

Now, I want to print this array with the string number. For instance, if the user inputs `M` strings, where `M < N` strings, it should print

```
    1  string_1
    2  string_2
    :  :
    M  string_M
```

However, if `M > N` then it should print

```
  M-N  string_(M-N)
M-N+1  string_(M-N+1)
    :  :
    M  string_M
```

I have tried several things and I can't quite make it work. Here is simplified version of my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 10                                      /* max size of array */
#define BUFF_MAX 50                               /* max size of buffer */
int M = 0;                                        /* input count */
char A[N][BUFF_MAX];                              /* should i initialize this? */

void displayArray() {                        
    for (int h = 0; h < M; h++) {                 /* print the elements */
        printf("%2d  %s\n", h + 1, A[h]);         /* this doesn't number properly */
                                                  /* and needs to be modified */
    }
}

int main(void) {
    while(1) {                                    /* keep reading from the user */
        char input[BUFF_MAX];
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);       /* read input from user */
        strcpy(A[M], input);                      /* copy input into array */
        M++;                                      /* i might need some modulo here */

        if (M >= N) {                             /* if user inputs more than N */
            for (int i = N - 1; i > 0; i--) {     /* shift the array */
                strcpy(A[i], A[i - 1]); 
            }
        }
        if (!strcmp(input, "hist"))
            displayArray();
    }    
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This code inputs only a single string (apart from not compiling). Also, what you are getting instead of the expected result?

Comment: @Inspired, this is more or less pseudocode. I didn't want to include everything for the sake of clarity. I will modify it slightly so it's more easy to understand. I am seeking a general way of solving this, so it's more a general question than a debug one.

Comment: I think if you give us the whole code is much better than the pseudocode because this latter does nothing but confusing me honestly ! @iHubble I get the idea but I want to see how you did it so it will be easy to fix it !

Comment: NB: `#define N = 10;` is wrong; you should write `enum { N = 10 };` or `#define N 10`.

Comment: All the shifting is modestly pointless -- a waste of energy.  Keep a record of the first valid entry and the next available entry for overwriting.  When one of the numbers reaches the upper bound, wrap it back to zero.  When the next available entry is the first valid entry, overwrite the first valid entry and increment the first valid entry tracker to go to the next.  Rinse and repeat.

Comment: he can keep a record of the number of inputs and do the strcpy with array of subscript `(number_inputs -1) mod N` which can do the trick !

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, can you elaborate more into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code with some changes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 10                                      /* max size of array */
#define BUFF_MAX 50                               /* max size of buffer */
int M = 0;                                        /* input count */
char A[N][BUFF_MAX];                              /* should i initialize this? */

void displayArray()
{
    int h;
    //you need to change the condition of for in order to print
    // the adequate number of elements
    for ( h = 0; h < (M>N?N:M); h++)                   /* print the elements */
    {
        printf("%2d  %s\n", h + 1, A[h]);         /* this doesn't number properly */
        /* and needs to be modified */
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    while(1)                                      /* keep reading from the user */
    {
        char input[BUFF_MAX];
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin); /* read input from user */
        // you need to add the condition below because the fgets include the newline
        // if the user hit enter after each input
        if(input[strlen(input)-1]=='\n')
            input[strlen(input)-1]='\0';
        // note that the subscript of the array is changed in order to
        // get the desired input A[ M % N ]
        // so the sequence of index will be 0 1 2 ... N-1 0 1 2 etc.
        strcpy(A[M % N], input);                      /* copy input into array */
        M++;                                      /* i might need some modulo here */

        if (!strcmp(input, "hist"))
            displayArray();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind that your code doesn't have a break point in order to exit the program. You need to add a `break` or `return` or `goto` inside the `while` loop to finish its execution !!

Comment: This works quite nicely, but the numbering is still from 1 to N. I would like it to be from M-N to M. I can easily fix this, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I had in mind. Note that I avoid 'infinite loops' and the program detects EOF and stops upon EOF.  Entering `hist` triggers a print operation but that line is not saved in the history.  Also, if you're observant, you'll note that there are only 9 entries saved in the 10-line buffer.  If you must have 10 lines on display, increase N by 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 10          /* max size of array */
#define BUFF_MAX 50   /* max size of buffer */

int M = 0;            /* monotonic input count */
int first_valid = 0;
int first_avail = 0;
char A[N][BUFF_MAX];

static
void displayArray(int v1, int v2)
{
    int h = v1;
    int x = M - N + 1;
    if (x < 0)
        x = 0;
    while (h != v2)
    {
        printf("%2d  %s\n", ++x, A[h++]);
        if (h >= N)
            h = 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char input[BUFF_MAX];
    while (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) != 0)
    {
        int len = strlen(input);
        if (input[len-1] == '\n')
            input[--len] = '\0';
        if (strcmp(input, "hist") == 0)
            displayArray(first_valid, first_avail);
        else
        {
            strcpy(A[first_avail++], input);
            M++;
            if (first_avail >= N)
                first_avail = 0;
            if (first_avail == first_valid)
            {
                if (++first_valid >= N)
                    first_valid = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
Line 1
hist
 1  Line 1
line 2
hist
 1  Line 1
 2  line 2
line 3
xyz 4
asd 5
hist
 1  Line 1
 2  line 2
 3  line 3
 4  xyz 4
 5  asd 5
Emergency 6
Helpline 7
hist
 1  Line 1
 2  line 2
 3  line 3
 4  xyz 4
 5  asd 5
 6  Emergency 6
 7  Helpline 7
Looping Later 8
Last Line Before Recycling 9
hist
 1  Line 1
 2  line 2
 3  line 3
 4  xyz 4
 5  asd 5
 6  Emergency 6
 7  Helpline 7
 8  Looping Later 8
 9  Last Line Before Recycling 9
First lot of recycling 10
hist
 2  line 2
 3  line 3
 4  xyz 4
 5  asd 5
 6  Emergency 6
 7  Helpline 7
 8  Looping Later 8
 9  Last Line Before Recycling 9
10  First lot of recycling 10
Keep going
Dozens of lines
Bad Luck
A fortnight
hist
 6  Emergency 6
 7  Helpline 7
 8  Looping Later 8
 9  Last Line Before Recycling 9
10  First lot of recycling 10
11  Keep going
12  Dozens of lines
13  Bad Luck
14  A fortnight
```

Comment: This answer is better as calling `hist` at the beginning does not get numbered as a negative number like the other solution. Will definitely use this one.